# PHP preg_match with Croatian Characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, but with little bit of searching on StackOverflow I managed to get what I want (If 2+ words are seperated by comma then it returns true and returns false if that isn't the case or the word ends with comma but nothing after), except I am having a problem with Croatian characters (č,ć,ž,đ,š upper and lowercase). My current `preg_match` looks like

```
 if (preg_match('/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*,\\s*)+(\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))$/', $data)) 
{
   //do stuff

}
```

But the problem with this approach is it won't return true if it has `Č`, `ć`, `ž`... and I know that is because of `[a-zA-Z]` that doesn't "look" for this characters. So, my question is how to write a regex that will return true with Croatian characters. And also if this could be done easier feel free to comment, as I would like to hear your suggestions on that. BTW, I have done this with the help of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: You could try to match them with `\p{L}` and `u` option: `if (preg_match('/^(([\\p{L}0-9]+\\s*,\\s*)+(\\s*)([\\p{L}0-9]+))$/u', $data)) `

Comment: @stribizhev it works! thank you. Can you explain that part you added a bit (new to this) if it isnt a problem and also put it as an answer so i can check it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\p{L}` shorthand class and `u` option makes it possible to match Unicode letters.

[This program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSU0tSzBmaVhMVWc) returns `FOUND!`:

```
$data = "Čdd, ćdd, žddd";
if (preg_match('/^(([\\p{L}0-9]+\\s*,\\s*)+(\\s*)([\\p{L}0-9]+))$/u', $data)) 
{
  echo "<h1>FOUND!</h1>";
}
```

As per [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

> You can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category
>   with `\p{L}`.

and [its another page devoted to PHP regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html):

> You should specify `/u` for regular expressions that use `\x{FFFF}`, `\X` or
>   `\p{L}` to match Unicode characters, graphemes, properties or scripts.
>   PHP will interpret `'/regex/u'` as a UTF-8 string rather than as an
>   ASCII string.

Also, see one of the examples at [preg_match function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) documentation page:

> For those who search for a unicode regular expression example using
>   `preg_match` here it is:
>
> Check for Persian digits `preg_match( "/[^\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}\x]+/u" ,
>   '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰' );`